# PowerShell - Why do I have to state the New-PSSession Variable again?

Tags: powershell

So I am running an Invoke-CimMethod to push an Enable-PSRemoting command to target computer. Then run an Invoke-Command using PS-Session as a parameter. The two scripts work separately, but if I run them together I keep getting this error:

```
Copy-Item : The runspace state is not valid for this operation.
```

I had to restate the $session variable like so in order for it to run. I have bolded and highlighted the line below. My question is why?

```
$env:hostname = 'PC1'
$Session = New-PSSession $env:hostname
$DestinationPath = "C:\windows\temp"

$SessionArgs = @{
     ComputerName  = $env:hostname
     Credential    = $credential
     SessionOption = New-CimSessionOption -Protocol Dcom
 }
 $MethodArgs = @{
     ClassName     = 'Win32_Process'
     MethodName    = 'Create'
     CimSession    = New-CimSession @SessionArgs
     Arguments     = @{
         CommandLine = "powershell Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList 'Enable-PSRemoting -Force'"
     }
 }

Invoke-CimMethod @MethodArgs


Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock { Param($Destination) New-Item -Path $Destination -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}  -ArgumentList $DestinationPath

Copy-Item -Path "\\shared\drive\foo\bar\" -Destination "C:\windows\temp\ZScaler" -Recurse -force

############Restated here#############    

$Session = New-PSSession $env:hostname

############Restated here#############    

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {

$msbuild = "C:\Windows\Temp\Installer\Installer.msi"
$arguments = "/quiet"
Start-Process -FilePath $msbuild -ArgumentList $arguments -Wait -Verbose

 }

$Session | Remove-PSSession
```

Comment: `New-PSSession` needs `PSRemoting` to be enabled in the first place to be able to create a session using its default protocol. So, you don't have to restate the variable again if you place/assign it after `Invoke-CimMethod`.

Comment: `Enable-PSRemoting -Force` is only needed once and then it's set forever (unless disabled again).

I'm guessing that WinRM is reset between the two Invoke-Commands since `Enable-PSRemoting` will take a litle while to run through.